# how to iterate in the list until python finds certain word?

Tags: python, pandas, list

i am trying to iterate over below list which is retrieved from HTML table

```
table = pd.read_html(url)
```

i have extracted the 3rd table :

```
table1 = table[2]
```

i am trying to count upto certain word in list variable table1. the output structure of the list is shown below

```
      0        1        2                <----------headers
1     A        AA       BBB
2     B        BB       CCC
3     C        CC       CCC
4     D        DD       DDD
5    catchme   catchme  catchme
6     E        FF       FFF
7     G        GG       GGG
```

when i try to print the type of the variable table1 which the above output is stored, it is shown as below:

```
<class 'list'>
```

How to count until python can find  the word that contains "catch" in the above list?
So that expected output would be : **4**

```
      0         0        1                   <----------headers
1     A        AA       BBB                  <---------- 1
2     B        BB       CCC                  <---------- 2
3     C        CC       CCC                  <---------- 3
4     D        DD       DDD                  <---------- 4
5    catchme   catchme  catchme              <--- found catch- exit loop
6     E        FF       FFF
7     G        GG       GGG
```

so far my code as shown below

```
        for phrase in table1:        #variable stored list
         print(phrase)
         if 'catchme' in phrase:
            finalinput = ['catchme'] + [i]
         else :
            i = i+1
```

but the above code is only looping through A AA BBB and it is exiting the loop.

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you need to iterate on the other axis. Without the dataset from the url, it is hard to say for certain because I don't know how your data is stored.

Comment: Thanks to reply @falafelocelot , the HTML table when i am trying to print , the structure is exactly same as above

Comment: Is it just a basic python 2d list? Is it a dataframe?

Comment: its a 2d list @falafelocelot, thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think first element of your list might be having pandas dataframe object.

Try following,

```
table[0][table[0].isin(['catchme']).any(axis=1)].index[0]
```

For example, I tried to read from following url and got list type object in output but when I tried to traverse it i found the dataframe object at 1st index.

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://www.railyatri.in/trains-between-stations")
df[0][df[0].isin(['Madgaon (MAO)']).any(axis=1)].index[0]
# output 4
```

**It happens because, `pandas.read_html()` function returns list of dataframes instead of dataframe object.**

Comment: Hi @O.T.B Harmony Limited , if your query is resolved please mark the answer as accepted, else please comment if there is any error or unexpected output is coming in your case.

Comment: Hi @vedant thankyou for reply, but the website i was trying to get has 3 tables in it, so when i was accessing 2nd table, i have to use df = df[2] . this is making the change the data type to list , is there any solution for this?. thankyou in advance

Comment: It might be a nested list in your case, Did you tried accessing df[2][0] ?

Comment: i ma getting this error raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/blabla/Desktop/testmain.py", line 126, in <module>
    print(table3[2][0])
  File "C:\Users\blablai\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\blabla\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 2

Comment: Try `print(table3[2].iloc[0])`

Comment: it was giving the same error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/blab bla/Desktop/testmain.py", line 126, in <module>
    print(table3[2].iloc[0])
  File "C:\Users\blabla\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\bla bla\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 2

Comment: Key error generally means the key doesn't exist. i got this one google, thanks for reply

Comment: Hi , i tried to print the variable table3 , its showing as <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: So now you can directly apply like this:
`table3[table3.isin(['catchme']).any(axis=1)].index[0]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233516/discussion-between-vedant-vasishtha-and-o-t-b-harmony-limited).

Answer (score 1):

A really simple solution is to just iterate through the 2D list and break when you encounter the condition

```
catchphrase = 'DD'
catchphrase_row = None
for index, row in table1.iterrows():
    if any(catchphrase in r for r in row.to_list()):
        catchphrase_row = index
        break

# Use pandas just to show the data
print(pd.DataFrame(table1))

# Show where the catchphrase was found
print(f'{catchphrase} found in row {catchphrase_row}')
```

Outputs

```
   0   1    2
0  A  AA  AAA
1  B  BB  BBB
2  C  CC  CCC
3  D  DD  DDD
4  E  EE  EEE
5  F  FF  FFF
6  G  GG  GGG
DD found in row 3
```

Comment: i am getting this error i was getting this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\blbla\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

Comment: i tried to print the variable table1 , its showing as <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: Okay you mentioned above that it is a 2D list not a dataframe. I updated my answer to assume table1 is a DataFrame.

Comment: i was getting this error TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable.  but when i print the variable type its showing <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>